# Objectmapper.writeValueAsString returning null

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, jackson-databind, objectmapper

I am doing unit testing with Junit and Mockito for a service class

I have mocked the ObjectMapper in Test Class as below

```
@Mock
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

then call to actual class method,
I am using fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.

**Actual code in service class**

```
Map<String, String> ackMessage = new HashMap();
ackMessage.put("ID", "123");
String **json** = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(ackMessage);
```

But this **json** string is getting null while debugging

I have autowired the Object mapper in my service class,

@Autowired
ObjectMapper objectMapper;

below code is how I get the ObjectMapper

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
return new ObjectMapper();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for doubting, but I'm pretty sure [`ObjectMapper#writeValueAsString(...)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writeValueAsString(java.lang.Object)) cannot technically return `null`. What the exact value of `json` in your above snippet? Which version of Jackson are you using? Can you share how `objectMapper` is initialised?

Comment: @sp00m : Figured that out, I have rephrased it

Comment: Ah yes, this makes more sense now. Why do you want to pass a mocked instance of `ObjectMapper` to your service class? Can't you simply pass a real instance, i.e. obtained via `new ObjectMapper()`? If for some reason you do really need to mock it, you can use `when(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(any())).thenCallRealMethod();`, but it kind of defeats the purpose of a mock.

Comment: Actually I am new to mockito, when(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(anything())).thenCallRealMethod(); but still the issue persist the String json is null